# How to get instance of needed class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I want to create a scheduler custom control in WPF. Also I want that this
control be generic, so for example scheduler can save events about notes, workers, meetings etc.

So I need one interface lets say IContract, which will have SaveEvent(), EditEvent() etc. methods.
Every specific class (Note, Meeting...) must implement that interface.
Because of that, in my view model for scheduler if I want to save event, I will do that via interface.

But question is, how can I pass this instace ("contract")

```
IContract contract = new Meeting();
```

to the scheduler view model? Someone who will use my custom control will just put this peace of code in some XAML

```
<local:Scheduler/>
```

Now I can do something like this: `<local:Scheduler instanceClass="Meeting"/>`
and than in scheduler view model via reflection get instanace. Is that good solution?

Is there another way?

Comment: If "generic" in your question means "control will be generic type", then don't do that. It's a very bad idea - WPF infrastructure won't handle this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to create the view model class somewhere else, where you manually set the instance to use. Then bind that instance to the view.

Something like this:

```
<local:Scheduler DataContext="{Binding Event}"/>
```

Optionally you could create another property than `DataContext` for the binding.

Comment: I am not sure that I understad. I have Scheduler.xaml where view contains some calendar, next and previous button etc.
ViewModel for that view is SchedulerViewModel class, where I keep information about current date in calendar, implements commands for buttons etc.

Your solution will change my view model? I can't do this. Also because custom control need to be generic how can customer of this control manually set the instance in SchedulerViewModel? I am pretty sure
that I understand something bad, so can you explain again please?

Comment: I understand now what you want to say, and that can be a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. Sorry I didn't have the time to answer your comment before. If you need anything, let me know.